# MVC 4 project using a class library EF model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Using an EF model in the **Models folder** in my MVC 4 project, I succeeded to display data in a razor view using a coded class named **Prod** and a controller method as next:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Prod> Pr = from p in db.Products
                                    select new Prod
                                    {
                                        ProductId = p.ProductID, 
                                        ProductName = p.ProductName
                                    };
    return View(Pr); 
}
```

Now I am trying to do the same thing using a model in a class library instead of the current one, so I added to my solution a new class library, added then a model using the same connection string, and mapping the same entities, then added to my MVC project a reference to the new class library, and put at the top of both **MyController** and **Prod** class the next:

```
using MyClassLibrary;
```

Then I deleted the old model, now when I try to display the view, I get the following error:

***Unable to load the specified metadata resource.***

Any help please ?

Comment: Where is your connectionstring? find if it's in the web.config

Comment: The connectionstring is in the app.config in the MyClassLibrary project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your connectionstring in web.config in Mc4 web project

Comment: I think this is the beginning of the answer, web.config contained the old connection string `connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;` and now I have to replace this with `connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;` but I need here to make reference to the Class library project.

Comment: thanks it worked without referencing the path to the Class library model, upvoted you :)

Answer (score 1):

When you move or rename the project the data context (.edmx) is in the metadata part of the Entity Framework connection string has to change

you can try have

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.s‌​sdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;
```

instead of

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.s‌​sdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;
```

or try deleting your context and recreating it then check the connection string it adds automatically.

Comment: I have created a new model in the class library, that's why I have the connection string in the App.config instead of the Web.config, and then I deleted the context without deleting its connection in the web.config, that's why I got this stupid error.

Comment: I see surely the connection will not work if the connect is not existing anymore. Sounds like you sorted out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Mention the datasource in the connection string.

If you have not used any other web.config file for views. Use you generic web.config file and upload a connection string with New datasource name , user and password.